# Mailqueue in mailcow dockerized

Tags: mail-server, mailcow

I have one domain test.com and have 2 user user1 and user2 ,I want to  hold all mail from user1 in queue in mail cow how can i do ?
How can we do in Mai queue for specific user in mailcow.
I want to hold all mail of specific user in mailcow can I do ?
Wants to hold or queue mail from specific user , and after that will release from administrator.